# post not showing in laravel

Tags: post, laravel-5.6

there are four post in my 'posts' table. but it is showing 'no post'.

**in controller:**

```
use App\post;
public function index()
{
    $asd = post::all();
    return view ('posts.index')->with('post',$asd);
}
```

**in index.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
       <h1> Peoples</h1>
       <hr>
@if(count($post)>1)
       @foreach($post as $single_post)
          <p> {{$single_post->username}}  </p>
       @endforeach
@else
       <p> No Posts  </p>
@endif
@endsection
```

**I don't know why this is happening, please help needed!**

Comment: do you already `dd($asd)` first? If so please do the same in your `index.blade.php` with `@php(dd($post))` to make sure the data exist.

Comment: change this line use App\post;  with App\Post  It means change you small "p" With capital "P" in "post"

Answer (score 0):

in controller:

```
use App\post;
public function index()
{
    $posts = post::get();
    return view ('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

in posts/index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
       <h1> Peoples</h1>
       <hr>
@if(count($post)>1)
       @foreach($posts as $post)
          <p> {{$post->username}}  </p>
       @endforeach
@else
       <p> No Posts  </p>
@endif
@endsection
```